# when is argument object created?

Tags: javascript, scope, arguments, executioncontext

In [this](http://davidshariff.com/blog/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript/) blog post, it says that the argument object is created and assigned its value during creation of execution context, before any code is executed. 
However, in the book, [YDKJS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch1.md)  by Kyle Simpson, there is an example that looks like this,

```
function foo(a) {
  console.log( a ); // 2
}

foo( 2 );
```

and he says that the assignment of value '2' to the argument 'a' happens after the creation of execution context and during the code execution.
I've been trying to find a scenario where both would make sense but they seem like total opposite claims. When is the argument object created exactly? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the arguments list object is [created on the caller side](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-calls).

Then it's passed into the [`EvaluateDirectCall`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-evaluatedirectcall) (or any other internal method that ends up calling a function) and then the [execution context is created](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-execution-contexts).

And after that when code evaluates - the [references to the variables](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-resolvebinding) are obtained from the execution context.

All from above in details: [`FunctionDeclarationInstantiation`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation)

Comment: Thanks! so is the blog post wrong when it says "Create the arguments object, check the context for parameters, initialize the name and value and create a reference copy."?

Comment: I think it's the same as what I explained

Comment: I think I was confusing about the argument object and the variables that are in the parameter. thanks for clarifying. it really helped.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the blog, it is reffering to the [`arguments object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) (mdn link) , not the local variables, of which a is one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I thought arguments are like local variables. and in the link you gave me, it says "The arguments object is a local variable available within all functions." So when does the assignment of 2 into variable a happens? during the creation of execution context of after?

Comment: @oneandwholly it depends what you mean by 'arguments'. note that "The arguments object is an Array-like object **corresponding** to the arguments passed to a function."